# Global functions with dataweave operators?

Tags: mule, mule-el, dataweave

I've few data weave functions which needs to be reused in different places in the flow. but these are using dataweave operators such as pluck. So is there a way to make them global.

```
%function formatterm(a)  (a pluck (null when $==null otherwise "term" : {'$$':$})) -null
```

`%function formatterms(a)  (a pluck (null when  $==null otherwise "terms" : {'$$':$})) -null`
`%function formatquerystring(a) (a pluck (null when $==null otherwise ("query_string" : "query": '$$' ++ ':' ++ $) )) - null`

Thanks
Sushma

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global MEL function. From MEL you can call dataweave, example:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mel-dataweave-functions

See https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mel-dataweave-functions for details.

You have to be careful with quoting:

```
def formatquerystring(a) { 
return dw("("+ a + " pluck (null when $==null otherwise 
           (\"query_string\" : \"query\": '$$' ++ ':' ++ $) )) - null")
}
```

works for me. But with this you are dynamically creating a dwl script which has to be compiled. And beware of code injection.

May be its better to write your formatquerystring in MEL.

Comment: Actually i tried to refer the example and defined the global function as   <configuration doc:name="formatquerystring_globalFunction">
 <expression-language>
  <import class="org.mule.util.StringUtils" />
  <global-functions>
                 def formatquerystring(a) {
                     return dw("(a pluck (null when $==null otherwise ("query_string" : "query": '$$' ++ ':' ++ $) )) - null")
                 }
  </global-functions>
 </expression-language>
</configuration>, but this function is not readable within dataweave.